# Apple silicon DTK && Xcode12.2 rc && arm64 ios simulator && building for ios sim, but linking ios

Tags: ios, arm64, xcode12, apple-silicon

if use apple silicon dtk to run project , have same problem ,how to fix ? Device: DTK mac mini, Xcode version: 12.2 rc, run to ios simulator which arch is arm 64. Throw error : building for iOS Simulator, but linking in object file built for iOS, for architecture arm64

Answer (score 0):

If you get a `building for iOS Simulator, but linking in object file built for iOS` error in Xcode, you'll need to set these `Build Settings` on both your main project and Pods project.

[image: build settings for M1]